# jQuery adding easing breaks animations that come after. Syntax Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm adding animations to a website, and having a bit of a hard time adding easing. I can get the entire animation sequence to run correctly, but when I try to define the easing, the animations break on all the animations that come after the first element where I define easing.

The basic animation sequence is the bottom half the page fades in and flies up to meet the top half. Then three buttons fade in and fly up sequentially to their designated locations. It looks alright, but it would look a lot better with `easOutBounce`.

I have now been wrestling with this for too long, trying to figure out why adding the easing breaks my code. I'm guessing my syntax is incorrect.

THIS code works on all elements:

```
jQuery( '.front-page-content-wrap' ).animate( {marginTop: 0, opacity: 1}, 600, function(){
    jQuery( "#box-button-1" ).animate( { bottom: 78, opacity: 1 }, function(){
       jQuery( "#box-button-2" ).animate( { bottom: 78, opacity: 1 }, function(){
         jQuery( "#box-button-3" ).animate( { bottom: 78, opacity: 1 } );
       } ); 
    } );  
});
```

BUT this code doesn't. When I run this code, it does add the easing and it still works on the `.front-page-content-wrap`, and the `#box-button-1`, but then it stops.

```
jQuery( '.front-page-content-wrap' ).animate( {marginTop: 0, opacity: 1}, 600, function(){
    jQuery( "#box-button-1" ).animate( { bottom: 78, opacity: 1 }, { easing: 'easeOutBounce' }, function(){
       jQuery( "#box-button-2" ).animate( { bottom: 78, opacity: 1 }, { easing: 'easeOutBounce' }, function(){
         jQuery( "#box-button-3" ).animate( { bottom: 78, opacity: 1 }, { easing: 'easeOutBounce' } );
       } ); 
    } );  
});
```

Any ideas?

PS, I'm using jQuery as the variable identifier instead of $, because I'm working in wordpress which runs in no-conflict mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntax: [`.animate( properties, options )`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options)

```
jQuery( '.front-page-content-wrap' ).animate( {marginTop: 0, opacity: 1}, 600, function(){
    jQuery( "#box-button-1" ).animate( { bottom: 78, opacity: 1 }, { easing: 'easeOutBounce', complete: function(){
       jQuery( "#box-button-2" ).animate( { bottom: 78, opacity: 1 }, { easing: 'easeOutBounce', complete: function(){
         jQuery( "#box-button-3" ).animate( { bottom: 78, opacity: 1 }, { easing: 'easeOutBounce' } );
       }}); 
    }});  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/42BjC/

Comment: That doesn't add the easing though. When I use that code, it defaults to the swing easing and ignores the 'easeOutBounce' all together.

Comment: No, I just have jQuery and the jQuery UI linked. No plugins. Is that plugin required?

Comment: Try adding a default duration (400 ms) before the easing. It shouldn't be necessary, though.

Comment: I have, that breaks the code. I've tried using several different syntax formats too. I've also tried the duration as a string and a number, since the documentation says it can be either.

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/96Kty/) works fine. Can you reproduce your issue on the same site?

Comment: Yes, give me a few minutes.

Comment: OK, here you can see the code for the buttons not working at all, which is weird, because the first one runs on my local server before it breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/aTLnu/ . If I change the easing to a string, then the whole animation runs, but the defined easing isn't used, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/aTLnu/1/

Comment: Also, I just noticed that while your fiddle works, it's using swing, and not easeOutBounce, which is the same problem I'm having. I've managed to get your animation to reproduce the exact problem I'm having. If you look at this updated fiddle, it uses the proper easing once, then stops. http://jsfiddle.net/96Kty/1/

Comment: IT WORKS! Gah! I must have seen that syntax 100 times while looking at the documentation and trying to figure this out. For some reason I just looked right past it. Tunnel vision out of frustration I guess. Thanks a bunch!